# Answer me with the update statement

Tags: sql-server

I have 101 records. and the prefix is a column.
[Insurance phone] is like 589-652-5256 and I have mistakenly done like

```
Substring ( EE.[Insurance Phone],4,3)
```

which result as -65 and I wanted it as 652 So I am writing update statement for same. I have different different phone number for 101 records. 
When I do a select statement I got each row's middle 3 number right, but if I use update statement then 625 [1st record of 101 record] number gets updated to all 101 records. 
Below are the select and update statements.

```
select 
    IC.COMPANY_NAME, EE.[Insurance Name], 
    substring (EE.[Insurance Phone], 5, 3) as phone
from
    Insurance_Companies_28012020 EE 
join 
    INS_COMPANIES IC on EE.[Insurance Name] = IC.COMPANY_NAME 
where 
    ic.IS_ACTIVE = 1 
    and [Insurance Phone] is not null

update BUSINESS_PHONE_NUMBERS 
set PREFIX = substring(EE.[Insurance Phone], 5, 3)
from Insurance_Companies_28012020 EE 
join INS_COMPANIES IC on EE.[Insurance Name] = IC.COMPANY_NAME 
where ic.IS_ACTIVE = 1 and [Insurance Phone] is not null
```

Comment: What do have to update? `BUSINESS_PHONE_NUMBERS` or `Insurance_Companies_28012020`?

Comment: Businee_phones, just forget select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your query should look like:

```
update  t1
set     t1.PREFIX = substring(EE.[Insurance Phone], 5, 3)
from    BUSINESS_PHONE_NUMBERS t1
inner join Insurance_Companies_28012020 EE on ee.KEY_COLUMN = t1.KEY_COLUMN -- here you should link these two tables
inner join INS_COMPANIES IC on EE.[Insurance Name] = IC.COMPANY_NAME 
where   ic.IS_ACTIVE = 1
        and [Insurance Phone] is not null
```

**Edited**:

Your update statement doesn't link tables `BUSINESS_PHONE_NUMBERS` and `Insurance_Companies_28012020`, which produces a Cartesian product in the execution plan, which leads to the strange behaviour of the end update result. You get the situation: you need to update N rows, but you have N*M rows with all possible combinations. It's hard to say which one of them will be selected to update. In your case, it is the first record from `Insurance_Companies_28012020` table.

Also, in your `UPDATE` statement you can add the condition to `WHERE` clause: `BUSINESS_PHONE_NUMBERS.KEY_COLUMN = EE.KEY_COLUMN`. This should give the same result as in my `UPDATE`.

Comment: This is a good answer. It would be a great answer if you explained **why** you need to use the BUXINESS_PHONE_NUMBERS table. That way the OP learns the reasoning of why this will work.

Comment: There is no column to link between ee and t1

Answer (score 0):

3o...,
Thanks for your answer it helped me to get to the exact destination. 
As I said there is no relation between ee and t1. So I need to change your update statement as below. And it worked fine for me.

```
update  t1
set     t1.PREFIX = substring(EE.[Insurance Phone], 5, 3)
from    BUSINESS_PHONE_NUMBERS t1
inner join INS_COMPANIES IC on IC.INS_COMPANY_ID = t1.OWNER_ID -- here you should link these two tables
inner join Insurance_Companies_28012020 EE on EE.[Insurance Name] = IC.COMPANY_NAME 
where   ic.IS_ACTIVE = 1
        and [Insurance Phone] is not null
```